# On hold event trigger the on click event

Tags: java, android, listview, event-handling

I have a ListView displayed on my screen.

When I click on an item (using setOnItemClickListener), you can rename it.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick() {}
```

When I hold on an item (using setOnItemLongClickListener), you can delete it.

```
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick() {}
```

However, when i hold on an item, it displays the "rename" window and the "delete" window, as if both were triggered.

Any idea on how to prevent this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: just try to call Longclicklistner before setting the onItemclick Listener. this solution may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

    return true; //<-- this should be TRUE, not FALSE   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Input Events](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#EventListeners) This returns a boolean to indicate whether you have consumed the event and it should not be carried further.

**If it return true to indicate that you have handled the event and it should stop here.**

**If it return false if you have not handled it and the event should continue to any other on-click listeners.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout and .bind to fix your problem with the shortest amount of logic:

```
var timeoutId = 0;

$('#myElement').mousedown(function() {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);
}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});
```